# How to add django rest framework permissions on specific method only ?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have following functions in rest API for User model. I want to set AllowAny permission on only POST request. Can someone help me out.

```
class UserList(APIView):
    """Get and post users data."""

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """Get users."""
        users = User.objects.all()
        serialized_users = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_users.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """Post users."""
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: what will happen in case of `GET` requests?

Comment: @RahulGupta In case of `GET` request Authentication is required.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**You can write a [custom Permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) `IsPostOrIsAuthenticated`** which will allow unrestricted access to `POST` requests but will allow only authenticated `GET` requests.

To implement the  custom permission `IsPostOrIsAuthenticated`, override the `BasePermission` class and implement `.has_permission(self, request, view)` method. The method should return `True` if the request should be granted access, and `False` otherwise.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsPostOrIsAuthenticated(permissions.BasePermission):        

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # allow all POST requests
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return True

        # Otherwise, only allow authenticated requests
        # Post Django 1.10, 'is_authenticated' is a read-only attribute
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated
```

So, all `POST` requests will be granted unrestricted access. For other requests, authentication will be required.

Now, you need to include this custom permission class in your global settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'my_app.permissions.IsPostOrIsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Comment: Might need to remove parenthesis from is_authenticated.

Comment: @BradenHolt Yes, post Django 1.10, its an attribute. Updated the ans. Thanks!

Comment: what about the case where you only want to allow a specific action called via POST, but disallow all other actions performed by POST ?

Comment: @Overdrivr Can you please provide an example with more details like which actions you are talking in POST or maybe another question.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

as per above URL you have to write one custom permission class

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (MyCustomAuthenticated,)
```

Write your own logic using AllowAny or IsAuthenticated inside MyCUstomAuthenticated based on POST and GET