# Django rest framework, tokken authentification, but not for the creation of users

Tags: django, authentication

I've been making a simple project with DJango and his rest framework, I want my users to authenticate with tokkens, the problem is that when I try to register users I get this message: "Authentication credentials were not provided".

Thi is a problem, a first time user should be able to register without authentication, any idea how can I make my users registrate witout tokkens?.

Here are my User serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', )
```

The user views:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

The urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'devices', views.DeviceViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', cosa.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

The problem is that when I tried to create a User with this command:

> http POST http://127.0.0.1:800/users/ username="Foo"
>   password"admin123456" email="foo@gmail.com"

I get this message:  "Authentication credentials were not provided".

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add django rest framework permissions on specific method only ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642175/how-to-add-django-rest-framework-permissions-on-specific-method-only)

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """

    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: With that I can create users, but if i try to obtain the tokken for those users I get the message: "Authentication credentials were not provided"

Comment: As I understand it, you would retrieve the token at the "/api-auth/", endpoint wouldn't you? And POST JSON like
{
 "username": "gurke",
 "password": "testtest123"
 
}

Comment: Yes, when I try this: http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/ username="test" password="test1234" I get that message.

Comment: what is this "cosa." ?I use in a very similar case: "from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token" and "url(r'^token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),"

Comment: It's just an import: from rest_framework.authtoken import views as cosa

Comment: Can you provide the Django console output? is it like [16/Apr/2018 20:14:42] "POST /token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 400 91

Comment: Yes, something like that: 
[16/Apr/2018 22:32:57] "POST /api-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 400 68

Comment: Thanks for the help! I finally found the problem, in my Serializer for User I use ModelSerializer, so I've to encode the password, once i encoded everything worked fine.