# how to set authentication and permission only on PUT requests in django REST in viewsets?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-viewsets

I have a `viewset` subclassing from `modelviewset`, I add next:

```
authication_classes = [SessionAuthentication,BasicAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Then, got following message when list, detail/retrieve and put requests.

> "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

What should i change to only give this message when I update the data ??

Comment: To help you out with your problem - it would be useful that you add the viewset class and also the request which you send to that endpoint to see how do you actually set the authentication credentials.

Comment: Here is a link to similar question kindly follow the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642175/how-to-add-django-rest-framework-permissions-on-specific-method-only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642175/how-to-add-django-rest-framework-permissions-on-specific-method-only 1.someone have answered a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Override `get_permissions` method on the `ModelViewSet` class.

**Example**:

```
class FooViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method != 'PUT':
            return []
        return super().get_permissions()
```